# how to copy files from linux to windows server , script or jenkins or azure devops?

Tags: devops

I have a requirement of copying files from Linux server to windows server and then check-in that to TFS. Please anyone let me know how to achieve and automate this .

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Whats is the problem that you are facing ? What are the available tools ?
E.hg: You can create batch file to SFTP the file using token based authentication to pull the file to local and then automate the checkin.

Ideally if the unix server is allowed access to the jenkins , directly do it from the unix box.

Are above solutions what you are looking for or are you looking for a script that does it .

Comment: Hi Lajit, It would be more useful if i can do it using jenkins and my unix box has access to Jenkins. Kindly let me know how i can do that.

Comment: I am really looking for this solution from few days and didnt get any from google that would help me.